# Function with user input and conditional statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm new to Javascript and am taking a class to learn more. Part of my homework was to make a button, that on click prompts you for how many cookies you want. Then gives you a total. The per cookie price is conditional on the amount of cookies bought.

This is what I have. When I try debuggers I'm told my else statement on line 25 in undefined.

So basically it loops through and then gives Total: $NaN and doesn't stop the loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <script>
        function buyCookies()
        {
            var numCookiesP = document.getElementById("numCookies");
            numCookiesP.innerHTML = parseInt (prompt("How many cookies would you like to buy?"));

            if(numCookies <= 5)
            {
                document.write("Total: $" + (numCookies * 1.25)).toFixed(2);
            }
            else if(numCookies <= 11)
            {
                document.write("Total: $" + (numCookies * 1.15)).toFixed(2);
            }
            else
            {
                document.write("Total: $" + (numCookies * 1.00)).toFixed(2);
            }

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Cookies" onclick="buyCookies()">

    <div>
        <p id="numCookies"</p>

    </div>
```

Comment: You want to assign the result of the prompt to the `numCookies` variable, not to `numCookiesP.innerHTML`?

Comment: "*doesn't stop the loop*" - I don't see any loop in your code?

Comment: I mean it doesn't finish loading. Not looping.

Comment: Your call: document.write("Total: $" + (numCookies * 1.00)).toFixed(2); Does that look OK? Match the parentheses and see what is passed to document.write. What is returned? Can you call ".toFixed(2)" on the result of calling document.write?

Comment: I need to prompt "how many cookies do you want to buy" 
take that user input and multiply it by a cookie price depending on how many they are buying and then write the total in a div tag.

I'm sure I'm doing it wrong and maybe I'm naming variables wrong on missing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

- you can't use `document.write` in an already loaded document - calling it will overwrite the current document. Setting `innerHTML` (or similar DOM manipulations) are the way to go. `document.write` is only for writing script tags or similar directly into the html parser stream when loading the document - you never really will use it.
- You didn't declare and initialise the `numCookies` variable - it doesn't contain the parsed number from the prompt, so the calculations yield `NaN`.

I guess you want this:

```
function buyCookies() {
    var numCookiesP = document.getElementById("numCookies");
    var numCookies = parseInt(prompt("How many cookies would you like to buy?"), 10);
    var factor = 1.0;
    if (numCookies <= 5) {
        factor = 1.25;
    } else if (numCookies <= 11) {
        factor = 1.15;
    }
    numCookiesP.innerHTML = "Total: $" + (numCookies * factor).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked brilliantly. We are at the point where we are supposed to forget doc.write and move on to DOM manipulations. But this is the first assignment that calls for it. So I ran into some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a few other things you'd want to tweak, but the following should at least clear up the $NaN:

```
<script>
        function buyCookies()
        {
            var numCookies = parseInt (prompt("How many cookies would you like to buy?"));
            var numCookiesP = document.getElementById("numCookies").innerHTML;

            if(numCookies <= 5)
            {
                document.write("Total: $" + (numCookies * 1.25).toFixed(2));
            }
            else if(numCookies <= 11)
            {
                document.write("Total: $" + (numCookies * 1.15).toFixed(2));
            }
            else
            {
                document.write("Total: $" + (numCookies * 1.00).toFixed(2));
            }

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Cookies" onclick="buyCookies()">

    <div>
        <p id="numCookies"></p>

    </div>
```

Comment: Fixed that and it's still giving me Total: $NaN and keeps looping.

Comment: There were a couple of other issues, but the above should work.